# Exception in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, io

**Error below are fixed by removing the declaration but another has appeared that did not previously exist.**

Receiving two errors, any insight would be great, thanks.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at ChatClient.(ChatClient.java:27)
>           at ChatClient.main(ChatClient.java:59)

From the following ChatClient:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChatClient
{  private Socket socket              = null;
   private BufferedReader  console   = null;
   private BufferedReader  streamIn   = null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;

   public ChatClient(String serverName, int serverPort, String userName)
   {  System.out.println("Establishing connection. Please wait...");
      try
      {  socket = new Socket(serverName, serverPort);
         System.out.println("Connected: " + socket);
         System.out.println("CTRL+C or type .bye to quit");
         start();
      }
      catch(UnknownHostException uhe)
      {  System.out.println("Host unknown: " + uhe.getMessage());
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {  System.out.println("Unexpected exception: " + ioe.getMessage());
      }
      String line = "";
      while (!line.equals(".bye"))
      {  try
         {  line = console.readLine();
            streamOut.writeBytes(line + '\n'); //Send console data to server socket
            String reply = streamIn.readLine(); //Recieve confirmation msg from server
            System.out.println( reply ); //Print the msg
            streamOut.flush();
         }
         catch(IOException ioe)
         {  System.out.println("Sending error: " + ioe.getMessage());
         }
      }
   }
   public void start() throws IOException
   {  console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //Changed console to BufferedReader
      streamIn  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   }
   public void stop()
   {  try
      {  if (console   != null)  console.close();
         if (streamOut != null)  streamOut.close();
         if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close(); //Is it good practice to close
         if (socket    != null)  socket.close();
      }
      catch(IOException ioe)
      {  System.out.println("Error closing ...");
      }
   }
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  ChatClient client = null;
      if (args.length != 3)
         System.out.println("Usage: java ChatClient host port username");
      else
         client = new ChatClient(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), args[2]);
   }
}
```

and this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at ChatServerThread.handleClient(ChatServerThread.java:41)
        at ChatServerThread.run(ChatServerThread.java:17)
```

from ChatServerThread:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

//public class ChatServerThread implements Runnable
public class ChatServerThread extends Thread
{  private Socket          socket   = null;
   private ChatServer      server   = null;
   private int             ID       = -1;
   private BufferedReader streamIn =  null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;

   public ChatServerThread(ChatServer _server, Socket _socket)
   {  server = _server;  socket = _socket;  ID = socket.getPort();
   }
   public void run() {
   try {
       handleClient();
   } catch( EOFException eof ) {
        System.out.println("Client closed the connection.");
   } catch( IOException ioe ) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
   }
}

   public void handleClient() throws IOException {
      boolean done = false;
      try {
      System.out.println("Server Thread " + ID + " running.");
      while (!done) {
        String nextCommand = streamIn.readLine();
        if( nextCommand.equals(".bye") ) {
           System.out.println("Client disconnected with bye.");
           done = true;
        } else {
           System.out.println( nextCommand );
           String nextReply = "You sent me: " + nextCommand.toUpperCase() + '\n';
           streamOut.writeBytes ( nextReply );
        }
     }
   } finally {
     streamIn.close();
     streamOut.close();
     socket.close();
   }
   }
   public void open() throws IOException
   {
      streamIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   }
   public void close() throws IOException
   {  if (socket != null)    socket.close();
      if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
      if (streamOut != null) streamOut.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show in the code what exact lines are causing these errors thanks.

Comment: What lines in your samples does the NPE correspond to.  Something on that line must be null.  Maybe you didn't call start() somewhere?

Comment: Updated answer from feedback below but another thread issue has appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's this line:

```
line = console.readLine();
```

`console` is still null. Even though you're calling `start()`, it doesn't do what you think it does:

```
public void start() throws IOException
{  BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

This declares a new *local* variable called `console`. It doesn't change the value of the *instance* variable called `console`. To do that, you should remove the declaration part:

```
public void start() throws IOException
{  
    console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    ...
```

Even with that change, you could get problems - because if that *does* throw an exception, here's what you're doing with it in the constructor:

```
catch(IOException ioe)
{  System.out.println("Unexpected exception: " + ioe.getMessage());
}
```

You're then continuing as if nothing had happened. Don't do that. You're not really "handling" the exception - so you should almost certainly either not catch it in the first place, or rethrow it in your catch block.

As an aside, your bracing style is *very* dense, very non-conventional, and inconsistent. I would *strongly* recommend against including code following an opening brace (on the same line). As it is, your code is pretty hard to read for anyone used to either of the (vastly) more common conventions, of:

```
if (foo) {
     // Do something
}
```

or

```
if (foo)
{
     // Do something
}
```

Comment: It was the declarations I had recently added.

Answer (score 1):

For the first exception, `console` is never assigned an object, so you can't call a method on it:

```
line = console.readLine();
//           ^ still null
```

Similarly, for the second exception,

```
streamIn.close();
//     ^ streamIn is still null
```

The problem is with re-stating the types of the variables in `start()`. This actually creates *new* variables that are local only to that method, and doesn't refer to the global ones of the same name.

Comment: What should be done about the `streamIn.close();`, this might be related to the second error I am receiving when closing the client via CTRL-C

Comment: @Astron just write `streamIn = new BufferedReader...` instead of `BufferedReader streamIn = new BufferedReader...`, as suggested by all.

Comment: Gotcha, did not know if you were inferring something else.

Answer (score 1):

Now it should run for client

```
public void start() throws IOException
   {  console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //Changed console to BufferedReader
      streamIn  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your start method

```
public void start() throws IOException
{  BufferedReader console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //Changed console to BufferedReader
  BufferedReader streamIn  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  DataOutputStream streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
```

}

You declare new **local** variables, rather than, as I think you intended, allocating the instance variables you already declared. If you change it to

```
public void start() throws IOException
{  console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); //Changed console to BufferedReader
  streamIn  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
  streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
}
```

It should work

You make the same error in the `open()` method of your second class

Answer (score 1):

This is because, console is null. To fix the problem, modify your `start();` method as:

```
public void start() throws IOException
{
    console = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    streamIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
}
```