# Exception in thread upon client disconnect

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, io

When a client disconnects using CTRL-C or the connection is terminated the server should produce a message stating that it has done so rather then producing an exception as follows:

> Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
>           at ChatServerThread.handleClient(ChatServerThread.java:31)
>           at ChatServerThread.run(ChatServerThread.java:17)

It began exhbiting this behavior after I converted from read/writeUTF() to readLine() and writeByte() respectively, and having the server respond to the client with what the client sent. See [Exception in thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9504806/666891) for details.

Question is how to get the EOFException to functionality to work again so that *Client closed the connection.* is printed verse the exception message. Line 31 is `if( nextCommand.equals(".bye") ) {`

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

//public class ChatServerThread implements Runnable
public class ChatServerThread extends Thread
{  private Socket          socket   = null;
   private ChatServer      server   = null;
   private int             ID       = -1;
   private BufferedReader streamIn =  null;
   private DataOutputStream streamOut = null;

   public ChatServerThread(ChatServer _server, Socket _socket)
   {  server = _server;  socket = _socket;  ID = socket.getPort();
   }
   public void run() {
   try {
       handleClient();
   } catch( EOFException eof ) { \\This does not seem to be working now and it previously was
        System.out.println("Client closed the connection.");
   } catch( IOException ioe ) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
   }
}

   public void handleClient() throws IOException {
      boolean done = false;
      try {
      System.out.println("Server Thread " + ID + " running.");
      while (!done) {
        String nextCommand = streamIn.readLine();
        if( nextCommand.equals(".bye") ) {
           System.out.println("Client disconnected with bye.");
           done = true;
        } else {
           System.out.println( nextCommand );
           String nextReply = "You sent me: " + nextCommand.toUpperCase() + '\n';
           streamOut.writeBytes ( nextReply );
        }
     }
   } finally {
     streamIn.close();
     streamOut.close();
     socket.close();
   }
   }
   public void open() throws IOException
   {
      streamIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
      streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
   }
   public void close() throws IOException
   {  if (socket != null)    socket.close();
      if (streamIn != null)  streamIn.close();
      if (streamOut != null) streamOut.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Related to previous recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504806/exception-in-thread

Comment: Which is line 31?  That's the same feedback I had to give on your last question.  Please help us out.

Comment: Question is how to get the EOFException to functionality to work again so that _Client closed the connection._ is printed verse the exception message. Line 31 `if( nextCommand.equals(".bye") ) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is thrown from the second line:

```
String nextCommand = streamIn.readLine();
if( nextCommand.equals(".bye") ) {
```

Obviously the `nextCommand` is `null`. `streamIn` is a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), quoting JavaDoc of [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> Returns:
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, **or null if the end of the stream has been reached**

This is a different behaviour when compared to [`DataInputStream.readUTF()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF()):

> Returns:
>
> a Unicode string.
>
> Throws:
>
> **EOFException** - if this input stream reaches the end before reading all the bytes.

My guess is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> interrupts blocking `readLine()` and signalling end of stream.

Comment: So `readUTF` will read the Ctrl+C and allow `} catch( EOFException eof ) {`, if that's the case is there a way to fix it?

Comment: You're getting an NPE. You need to test for `nextCommand==null`.

Comment: @Astron: I quoted relevant parts of the Javadoc, see my updated answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison Have an example?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Thanks, I am going to determine if reverting to `readUTF()` is reasonable or if there is a fix. At this point it seems the `EOFException` is worthless.